# Adding the values of QN1 to QN33 in a dataset for each row in RStudio and Counting 0 (missing) values

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to analyse a dataset in R coming from a background in Stata.

I have 33 questions (titled Q1 to Q33) and was trying to iterate through these rather than just using a long line of code to add them all together. I am also aware of missing data and have converted these to 0, but also want to count the prevalence of them for when I calculate the average score.

The score calculation seems to work but the missing calculation doesn't, and it warns me that

> In if (QN == 0) { ... : the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

My code is

```
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel("MICRO DATASET EDITING.xlsx")
#Convert All Columns to Integers, ignore errors those are NAs
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(replace(x, is.na(x), 0)))
View(df)

###Calculate Total Scores###
Score <- 0
NumAnswered <- 33
Missing <- 0
for (x in 1:33) {
  QVal <- df[[paste("Q", x, sep = "")]]
  Score <- Score + QVal
  ifelse(QVal == 0, Missing <- Missing + 1)
}
df$Score <- Score
df$Missing <- Missing
```

I saw online that this could be due to the if statement so I changed it to

```
for (x in 1:33) {
  QVal <- df[[paste("Q", x, sep = "")]]
  Score <- Score + QVal
  ifelse(QVal == 0, Missing <- Missing + 1)
}
df$Score <- Score
df$Missing <- Missing
```

But this is still incorrect (it says all the answers are missing even though the score has been tallied up correctly)

Comment: *sorry my original code for the if statement was "if (QVal == 0){Missing <- Missing + 1}"

Comment: You can click the "edit" button under your question to correct it rather than adding a comment down here. The best thing you could do to make your question clearer would be to edit in a reproducible example. If you run `dput(df[1:5, paste0("Q", 1:5")])` that will give copy/pasteable R code to create the first 5 rows and 5 Q  columns of your data. Please run that and edit the result into your question.

Comment: But generally `ifelse()` doesn't work this way - it's good for vector input and same-size vector output.The way you are using it, you want `if(){}else{}` instead. But there's probably a much faster way with `rowSums` or something... it's just hard to tell without seeing what your input looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`R` is good for vectorised operations and for working with tabular data so that you can avoid loops.

There are 2 main "dialects" of `R`: base `R` and [`tidyverse`](https://www.tidyverse.org/) (they are not exclusive of one another!). Below is an example of how to achieve what you need in both but there are other ways.

N.B. the `|>` is the pipe operator (introduced in `R 4.2`, I think). It takes whatever is to the left of it and inserts it to the expression to the right of it *as its first argument*, so `mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)` is equivalent to `x |> mean(na.rm=TRUE)`.

```
## simulate data
set.seed(1234)
df <- sample(100) |>
  matrix(ncol=10) |>
  as.data.frame()
# change column names
names(df) <- paste0("Q_", 1:10)
# introduce NAs
df[sample(10, 4), 2] <- NA
> df
   Q_1 Q_2 Q_3 Q_4 Q_5 Q_6 Q_7 Q_8 Q_9 Q_10
1   28  70  92  42  71  98  19  27  55   34
2   80  79  67  43  85  35  65  12  33   53
3   22  NA  96   2  57  72  23  89  24   74
4    9  14  66  54   8  94  63  64  13   11
5    5  56  47  49  26  73  20   1  39   69
6   38  NA  81  99  17  50   7  83  68   61
7   16  93  48  51  58  10  52  95  87   59
8    4  NA   3   6  91  45  37  75  18   82
9   86  NA  41  77  60  25  31  97  44  100
10  90  40  32  29  76  46  88  36  15   30


# get indices of columns that start with Q_
cols_to_select <- grep("Q_", names(df))
```

- base `R` way:

```
# create sum score
df$sum <- df[ , cols_to_select] |>
  rowSums(na.rm=TRUE) # na.rm=TRUE removes NAs before calculating row sums
# count NAs per row
df$na <- df[ , cols_to_select] |>
  is.na() |> # returns logical, TRUE if value is NA
  rowSums()
```

- the `tidyverse` way:

```
# need to install tidyverse or at least dplyr
df <- df |> 
  dplyr::mutate( # mutate is used to create new columns
    # create sum scores
    sum = df |> dplyr::select(dplyr::starts_with("Q_")) |> rowSums(na.rm=TRUE),
    # count NAs per row
    na = df |> dplyr::select(dplyr::starts_with("Q_")) |> is.na() |> rowSums(na.rm=TRUE)
  )
> df
   Q_1 Q_2 Q_3 Q_4 Q_5 Q_6 Q_7 Q_8 Q_9 Q_10 sum na
1   28  70  92  42  71  98  19  27  55   34 536  0
2   80  79  67  43  85  35  65  12  33   53 552  0
3   22  NA  96   2  57  72  23  89  24   74 459  1
4    9  14  66  54   8  94  63  64  13   11 396  0
5    5  56  47  49  26  73  20   1  39   69 385  0
6   38  NA  81  99  17  50   7  83  68   61 504  1
7   16  93  48  51  58  10  52  95  87   59 569  0
8    4  NA   3   6  91  45  37  75  18   82 361  1
9   86  NA  41  77  60  25  31  97  44  100 561  1
10  90  40  32  29  76  46  88  36  15   30 482  0
```

For calculating mean scores directly, you can use `rowMeans(na.rm=TRUE)`.